# SQL join queries attempt

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm currently trying to write SQL join queries. I'm relatively new to this and I'm not sure if I did any errors especially in part c), d) and e).

*Figure1*: Database Schema

```
Customer
ID FirstName LastName DateOfBirth

Instructor
Id FirstName LastName

FitnessClass
Id ClassName Cost InstructorId

Subscription
CustomerId ClassId StartDate
```

what are the customer names who have subscribed for the fitness class with the name "Beginner Sumba".

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName 
FROM Customer, Subscription
WHERE
Customer.CustomerID = ClassName. Beginner Sumba
```

Comment: I'm just going to provide a useful link here - http://www.firstsql.com/tutor2.htm

Comment: I would probably read beginners guide.  it will save you a lot of time troubleshooting.  Everything wrong I see in your queries probably gets covered soon as the guide begins.  I would highly recommend you look at following playlist:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNObiptSMSI&list=PL08903FB7ACA1C2FB

Comment: User a proper `JOIN` syntax. https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php

Answer (score 2):

You have to JOIN tables by their IDs and then filter what you need in WHERE clause.

The appropriate solution for item A would be smtg similar to:

```
select c.FirstName, c.LastName
from Customer c
join Subscription s on (s.CustomerId = c.ID)
join FitnessClass f on (f.Id = s.ClassId)
where f.ClassName = 'Begginer Sumba'
```

Take a look and try to solve the others. Any further doubt please ask.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately none of your queries seem to be correct. You first have to get acquinted with the syntax. The help pages of all major DBMS are pretty good, you can either find BNF or flow charts and examples to learn the correct syntax (e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html or http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

I *highly recommend* that you use *aliases* and *join syntax*, it is more intuitive and easier to read.

a) I will show you how to solve this one, then you can give the other ones another shot.

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName
FROM Customer c JOIN
  Subscription s ON s.CustomerId = c.Id JOIN
  FitnessClass f ON f.Id = s.ClassId
WHERE f.className = 'Beginner Sumba'
```

You could also put the condition in the last join instead of the `where`, but I thought it's less confusing for beginners like this.